# Visitor pattern and logical operations

Tags: c#, design-patterns, visitor-pattern

Okay i've been strugling with this problem I'm having.

I have created a tree structure with logical nodes e.g. And, Or, Equals, Between.
I don't want these nodes to have anything more than an accept method for the visitor, because there will be more visitors with different implementations.

So for example i'm visiting the and. It first visits itself so i know i'm dealing with an and, then it is visiting the left and the right nodes. Which can be any of earlier said nodes.

The problem is, that I need a way of checking that I am finished with visiting the childnodes.
For example I want this output

> "And(Equals()/Or(Equals()/Between())"

But since I have no way of knowing when childs have been visited it will be someting like this.

> "And()Equals()/Or()Equals()/Between()

Any suggestions on how to overcome this problem?

Comment: Checking you are finished with visiting the child nodes? What do you mean? Aren't you finished at the end of the ```.accept()``` call? Are you doing it asynchronously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the tips jgauffin!
But I got something smaller working the way I want it to.

Started working with generics.

```
public abstract class Node
{
    public abstract T Accept<T>(IVisitor<T> visitor);
}

public interface IVisitor<T>
{
    T Visit(And element);
    T Visit(Or element);
    T Visit(Equals element);
}
```

So my visitor can implement it without any concern of the objects like this:

```
public string Visit(Or element)
{
   return "Or(" + element.Left.Accept(this) + "," + element.Right.Accept(this) + ")";
}
```

So my program just accepts the root node and will print out the string I mentioned before.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you liked the answer from @jgauffin you should vote it up and/or accept it.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to keep track of where you are in the tree when nodes are visited. To be able to do that you need to introduce some sort of context.

Something like this:

```
public class VisitContext
{
    // Visited node
    public VisitedType Visited { get; set; }

    // Visited node is the left child node
    public bool IsLeftNode { get; set; }

   // Visited node is the right child node
    public bool IsRightNode { get; set; }
}
```

So the visitor got this contract:

```
public interface IVisitor
{
    public void Visit(VisitContext context);
}
```

Now you just need to traverse it. The key is to have a protected overload that tells children which type they are. Do note the recursive calls.

```
public class VisitedType
{
    public void Accept(IVisitor visitor)
    {
        var context = new VisitContext{ Visited = this };
        visitor.Visit(context);

        _leftNode.AcceptAsLeft(context);
        _rightNode.AcceptAsRight(context);
    }

    protected void AcceptAsLeft(VisitContext context)
    {
        context.IsLeftNode=true;
        context.IsRightNode=false;
        visitor.Visit(context);

        _leftNode.AcceptAsLeft(context);
        _rightNode.AcceptAsRight(context);
    }

    protected void AcceptAsRight(VisitContext context)
    {
        context.IsLeftNode=false;
        context.IsRightNode=true;
        visitor.Visit(context);

        _leftNode.AcceptAsLeft(context);
        _rightNode.AcceptAsRight(context);
    }
}
```

Now you know when you go left and right in the tree, but you still doesn't know where in the tree you are. To do that let's introduce a lineage/breadcrumbs which tracks our current path.

```
public class VisitContext
{
    public VisitedType Visited { get; set; }
    public bool IsLeftNode { get; set; }
    public bool IsRightNode { get; set; }

    // this.
    public LinkedList<VisitedType> Lineage { get; set; }       
}
```

And update the visited type:

```
public class VisitedType
{
    public void Accept(IVisitor visitor)
    {
        var context = new VisitContext{ Visited = this, Lineage = new LinkedList<VisitedType>() };
        context.Lineage.AddLast(this);
        visitor.Visit(context);

        _leftNode.AcceptAsLeft(context);
        _rightNode.AcceptAsRight(context);
    }

    protected void AcceptAsLeft(VisitContext context)
    {
        //add a bread crumb
        context.Lineage.AddLast(this);
        context.IsLeftNode=true;
        context.IsRightNode=false;
        visitor.Visit(context);

        _leftNode.AcceptAsLeft(context);
        _rightNode.AcceptAsRight(context);

        //remove us when we've visited our children
        context.Lineage.RemoveLast();
    }

    protected void AcceptAsRight(VisitContext context)
    {
        //add a bread crumb
        context.Lineage.AddLast(this);
        context.IsLeftNode=false;
        context.IsRightNode=true;
        visitor.Visit(context);

        _leftNode.AcceptAsLeft(context);
        _rightNode.AcceptAsRight(context);

        //remove us when we've visited our children
        context.Lineage.RemoveLast();
    }
}
```

Now you should be able to trace the visits through the hierarchy. This works thanks to the recursive calls which will continue to build the breadcrumbs when going through the hierarchy.